# request.args.get('key') gives NULL - Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to pass the variable 'email' from the 'signup' method in my view to the 'character' method. However,

```
request.args.get('email')
```

is saving NULL into the database. I cannot figure out why.

Here is what shows up after passing the 'email' variable to '/character':

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/character?email=test%40test.com
```

Here is my code in 'views.py':

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET','POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('signup.html')
    email = request.form['email']
    return redirect(url_for('character', email=email))

@app.route('/character', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def character():
    if request.method == 'GET':     
        return render_template('character.html')

    email = request.args.get('email')

    password = request.form['password']
    name = request.form['username']
    temp = model.Actor(request.form['gender'], request.form['height'], request.form['weight'], request.form['physique'])
    user = model.User(name, email, password, temp)
    db.session.add(temp)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('movies'))
```

Everything else works just fine, it is just that 'email' is not being saved as 'test@test.com' and instead as NULL.

Thank you for your help ahead of time!

EDIT: 
Solved using sessions in Flask.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions

Comment: Can you post your model code, too? I suspect something is wrong in your User object, because otherwise this should work.

Comment: What does `User.__init__` look like? Are you sure it's expecting `email` in that position?

Comment: @RachelSanders added my model.py file above, thank you for your help!

Comment: @dirn please see model.py above, thank you!

Comment: @RachelSanders, I do not think it has to do with my model because if I set "email = 'test@test.com'" in my /character method it works just fine. Meaning that request.args.get is not grabbing 'email' from the URL

Comment: Accept the answer below @SunnyMalotrha

Answer (score 28):

When you submit your signup form, you're using POST. Because you're using POST, your form values are added to `request.form`, not `request.args`.

Your email address will be in:

```
request.form.get('email')
```

If you were hitting the URL `/characters?email=someemail@test.com`, and you weren't rendering a template immediately with:

```
if request.method == 'GET':     
    return render_template('character.html')
```

in your characters view, only then would you be able to access:

```
request.args.get('email')
```

Check out the [werkzeug request / response](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/?highlight=request) docs for more info.

**Edit:** Here's a full working example (minus your models stuff)

app.py

```
 from flask import request, Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for       

app = Flask(__name__)                                                      
app.debug = True                                                           


@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET','POST'])                              
def signup():                                                              
    if request.method == 'GET':                                            
        return render_template('signup.html')                              
    email = request.form['email']                                          
    return redirect(url_for('character', email=email))                     


@app.route('/character', methods=['POST', 'GET'])                          
def character():                                                           
    email_from_form = request.form.get('email')                            
    email_from_args = request.args.get('email')                            
    return render_template('character.html',                               
                           email_from_form=email_from_form,                
                           email_from_args=email_from_args)                


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                 
    app.run()
```

templates/signup.html

```
<html>                                                                     

Email from form: {{ email_from_form }} <br>                                
Email from args: {{ email_from_args }}                                     

</html>
```

templates/character.html

```
<html>                                                                     

<form name="test" action="/character" method="post">                       
    <label>Email</label>                                                   
    <input type="text" name="email" value="test@email.com" />              
    <input type="submit" />                                                
</form>                                                                    

</html>
```

Submitting the signin form (via POST) will populate `Email from form`

Hitting the url `http://localhost:5000/character?email=test@email.com` (via GET) will populate `Email from args`

Comment: Thanks for your response! That makes sense and I had tried that prior to posting this question. 'request.form.get('email')' still gives NULL. Any other ideas?

Comment: @SunnyMalotrha you should definitely accept the answer, it is very good and detailed.

Comment: This is a good example but did not solve my problem. I solved my problem using sessions. (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions)