# Using request args in Flask for a variable URL and second value returns as none

Tags: python, flask

URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/login?apple=exec&basket=app

Apple value returns as exec but basket value returns as None instead of app. Problem with picking up second value

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():

        a = str(request.args.get('apple', type = str))
        b = str(request.args.get('basket', type = str))
        return (b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: What version of python are you running, and what version of Flask?

Comment: Flask 1.0.2
Python 3.4.8

Comment: What happens if you change your `b` request to this: `b = request.args.get('basket', 'value')`? Does it output `value`?

Comment: it takes value as default then, it's returning execvalue instead of execNone

Comment: Odd. It should just work then. I am unable to replicate with the exact code you've posted and with the same URL with args. Have you tried just `?basket=app` without the `apple` arg? Have you tried a different argument name?

Comment: yeah, i don't understand what i am missing. with a single argument it works with second of any name it returns none

Comment: Please do a `print(request.args)` and let me know what the output is. It should be something like this: `ImmutableMultiDict([('basket', 'app'), ('apple', 'exec')])`

Comment: it's just ImmutableMultiDict([('apple', 'exec')]) .

Comment: And your URL is exactly this: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/login?apple=exec&basket=app`? Are you typing in a different language? Perhaps an encoding issue in your URL?

Comment: yeah it's exactly http://127.0.0.1:5000/login?apple=exec&basket=app . Encoding issue how can i find if it exists or remove it

Comment: Did you say this happens even if you were to change the values of exec and app? So, have you tried `apple=value1&basket=value2`?

Comment: yeah true, apple=value1&basket=value2 also returns value1None

Comment: Might I suggest you reinstall flask? `pip uninstall flask` and the reinstall it. `pip install flask`. You may need pip3 depending on your environment.

Comment: Also, see this post to see if this might clue you in on your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065900/request-args-getkey-gives-null-flask

Comment: uninstall didn't work, yeah sure will look into the link. thank you so much!

Comment: used webargs instead of  requests to take parameters from URL and it worked anyways I think I did some mistake with using requests

Comment: Interesting. Not sure what mistake you did. Ever flask application that I've written has used request.args, or request.form to get the data. I'm glad you at least figured out something.

Answer (score -1):

There is no issue with the code in picking up the argument, actually the thing is you cant return 2 items to browser. It just cannot pick them up (even though python is capable of returning more than 1 values).

The below code is proof that the values are being picked up correctly.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    a = request.args.get('apple')
    b = request.args.get('basket')
    return a+b


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Gives:

```
execapp
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why he would get `None` for the `b` value. That appears to be the issue. Even though his code works as is, there has to be something he has (version perhaps) which is causing him to get `None`

Comment: true i am getting value as execNone not execapp. How come you got execapp with same code. What version are you using and how do i make sure i am using the right one.

Comment: Btw request.args.get() retruns None if it is not able to get the value based on the key provided.  Try updating your requests version

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071256/how-to-update-upgrade-a-package-using-pip

Comment: Btw I have removed the unnecessary typecasting, please try the above code now!

Comment: Even after updating requests i am getting None. Please let me know if i am missing anything else